# Create jenkins.log in a customized path - linux

Tags: jenkins

I have a customized jenkins set up (it was made by another persone) and it does not have the jenkins.log, I try to enable by adding the env variable, but it does not work. it is possible to enable or create the jenkins.log in a customized path. Because is not working for me. ?

note: is not on /var/log/jenkins , we host several jenkins instances on the same machine :)

thanks

Comment: Hi Ely. Welcome to S.O

Comment: Do you have shell access to your linux?

Comment: How are starting your Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

From https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Logging

Linux

By default logs should be made available in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log, **unless customized in /etc/default/jenkins (for *.deb) or via /etc/sysconfig/jenkins (for */rpm)**

So, it looks like you can customize the logs location as per above.

`JENKINS_LOG=<custom_location>`

Comment: Hi, I tried to do that and it did not work..I restarted the dserver, but it looks like is not picking up the env variable :/

Comment: Where should I add it? This is a custom set up, so O add the variable on the dame file that the jenkins-home variable was, but is not working

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` file ?